# Dynamic credentials

Tags: azure, dynamic, azure-keyvault, hashicorp-vault, secrets

Does Azure Key Vault support dynamic secrets feature like Hashi Corp vault?

This feature is what required.
https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/db-credentials/database-secrets

This is what I could find about azure key vault.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/tutorial-rotation

Comment: Provide more details like your approach and what you have tried to help you out.

Comment: I just wanted to know whether it is possible in azure key vault to generate dynamic secrets for databases automatically.

Comment: Instead of looking for a feature-to-feature match, you should look into solving the problem using the best available solution. So instead of having Vault (or whatever) feed passwords in your Azure databases, look into [integrated authentication for Azure SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-overview?view=azuresql), a better solution overall if it meets your use case imho.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for dynamic secrets/credentials in Key Vault and no plans to implement it in near future.

Key Vault Team